# Restangular with Typescript confusing when 'restangularized' response object

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise, restangular, tsd

I am using Angular 1.5.x with TypeScript. For accessing a remote API I use restangular. As a summary this is my scenario:

My API has the following resource `http://localhost:53384/api/timezones`. Sending a request with the verb GET to that url returns a JSON array:

```
[
   {
      "code":"Dateline Standard Time",
      "name":"(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West"
   },
   {
      "code":"UTC-11",
      "name":"(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11"
   },
   {
      "code":"Hawaiian Standard Time",
      "name":"(UTC-10:00) Hawaii"
   }
]
```

Now in my client AngularJs application with TypeScript:

**Restangular configuration being *restangularProvider: restangular.IProvider***

```
restangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://localhost:53384/api");
```

**The TimeZone object representation in the client side with typescript**

```
module app.blocks {
    "use strict";

    export class TimeZone {
        public code: string;
        public name: string;
    }
}
```

**Factory(*restangular.IService*) to wrap the restangular *all* 'timezones' resource**

```
module app.services {
    factory.$inject = ["Restangular"];

    function factory(restangular: restangular.IService): restangular.IElement {
        return restangular.all("timezones");
    }

    angular
        .module("app.services")
        .factory("app.services.TimeZonesRestangular", factory);
}
```

**Service that uses *TimeZonesRestangular* to wrap its restangular functionality and return chained promises to whoever requests timezones in an asynchronous way**

```
module app.services {
    "use strict";

    export interface IStaticDataService {
        getTimeZones(): ng.IPromise<app.blocks.TimeZone[]>;
    }

    class StaticDataService implements IStaticDataService {
        constructor(private timeZonesRestangular: restangular.IElement) {
        }

        public getTimeZones(): ng.IPromise<blocks.TimeZone[]> {
            return this.timeZonesRestangular.getList()
                .then((timeZones: blocks.TimeZone[]) => {
                    return timeZones;
                }, (restangularError: any) => {
                    throw "Error retrieving time zones. Status: " + restangularError.status;
                });
        }
    }

    factory.$inject = ["app.services.TimeZonesRestangular"];

    function factory(timeZonesRestangular: restangular.IElement): IStaticDataService {
        return new StaticDataService(timeZonesRestangular);
    }

    angular
        .module("app.services")
        .factory("app.services.StaticDataService", factory);
}
```

**And finally in the controller using the service to get the 'timezones' asynchronously I have this statement**

```
//..other controller things not relevant for this sample
this.staticDataService.getTimeZones()
      .then((timeZones: blocks.TimeZone[]) => {
            this.timeZones = timeZones;
       });
```

**There are 2 PROBLEMS:**

1. The type definition for restangular (which I installed with `tsd install restangular --resolve --save`) tells me that the successCallback in the getTimeZones() method is a `promiseValue: any[]`, which is fine because it is indeed an array. I thought it would be an array of TimeZone[] and typescript compiles properly because it accepts `any[]`, but when debuggin I see that the successCallback promised value **it's not an array of TimeZone[]**. It has the properties I expected (`code` and `name`) but it also has many other things restangular-ish. An object within that array looks like this (plus some functions):

   ```
   {  
    "code":"Dateline Standard Time",
    "name":"(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West",
    "route":"timezones",
    "reqParams":null,
    "restangularized":true,
    "fromServer":true,
    "parentResource":null,
    "restangularCollection":false
   }
   ```

   As per https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/150 it looks as if my response had been "restangularized". Scary description for somebody new to restangular like myself..
   **What interface in restangular type definition should I use to represent the array of *restangularized* `TimeZone[]` ?**
2. Is there any example on how to achieve something similar with TypeScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little bit further I found out that the best way to handle this is by expecting a promised value of type `restangular.ICollection` (which inherits from `IService` and `Array<any>`) so that I can de-restangularize the response like this:

```
public getTimeZones(): ng.IPromise<blocks.TimeZone[]> {
            return this.timeZonesRestangular.getList()
                .then((restangularizedTimeZones: restangular.ICollection) => {
                    return restangularizedTimeZones.plain();
                }, (restangularError: any) => {
                    throw "Error retrieving time zones. Status: " + restangularError.status;
                });
        }
```

Now everthing seems to be fine and the response is, indeed, a promise of `TimeZone[]`